# Why if I try to git pull in master branch changes appear?

Tags: git, gitlab

I was creating a project and each feature is achieved via separate branch. So, before the creation of the separate branch I always do git pull in master branch to update the project with new changes done by the other devs. Oftentimes, on git pull in master I do not get changes that I need to commit, I mean, new changes automatically get merged and there is no need to commit the new changes. But, sometimes I get new changes that I need to commit here is the photo for clarification: [image: The photo]

The question is Why aren't new changes merged automatically and we need to commit them?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You seem to not fully understand how git is working: If you pull, you will only ever get changes that have already been committed. It's not possible to pull uncommited changes. Uncommited changes are results of changes in your local repository. You should read up about git, good points to start are the [git pro book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) and the [git tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info)

Comment: What does that screenshot show? What does the "76" imply? What **exactly** do you mean by _"sometimes I get new changes that I need to commit"_ after you do a pull from origin/master into your local master branch?

Comment: Are you saying that you had no local changes, you do a pull and immediately have new unstated changes? $5 says you have a line ending problem.  What does `git status` show before and after this pull.  What does `git diff` show?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to get changes from remote branch: git pull and git fetch.
If you run command git fetch, it will fetch all changes for current repo, but will not update master or any other branch. The next step would be either rebase your feature branch to master (if you would like to just get changes from master):

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Or you can merge master to your feature branch, which will create a merge commit and add all changes from master into history of your feature branch (I don't like merge option, prefer rebase, but it's up to preference of each developer).